# Downgrade EE2 from 2.7.3 to 2.6.1?

Tags: solspace-importer, 2.7.3

I have been importing thousands of entries using Solspace's Importer 2.2.2 on EE 2.6.1, and once I upgraded to EE 2.7.3 and thus also upgraded to Importer 2.2.3, I have gotten nothing but Internal Server Errors and cannot figure out the cause.

I'd like to just go back to the previous versions of EE/Importer. Is that a fairly easy process?

Comment: Do you have a backup of your EE setup *before* you upgraded EE? Always make sure you do, that way you can easily backtrack. Another solution would be to try to deal with the Internal Server Error: for example, where/when does this happen? What is the actual error? What fieldtypes did you import data in? Is the imported data well formatted for the used fieldtypes?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I do not have a backup from before the last upgrade.

The data I'm trying to import is from a large CSV (3 MB), although I know for a fact I have had perfect success importing similar-sized data files using the same fieldtypes (all text-based).

The error is occurring during the first "batch" each and every time, roughly a minute into the import. After that minute or so, a dialog box simply pops up alerting me of the Internal Server Error and goes back to the main Importer page. I had enabled an error log, but this error is not getting picked up.

Comment: Try using a much smaller CSV sample of your original CSV file, eg. a CSV containing just a few rows of data, and see if the import works successfully. Then, add rows until you see get error. This will tell you if you have badly formatted data in your CSV, which might be tripping Importer. Also make sure your CSV is in unicode/UTF-8, and have the correct delimiter and enclosure characters (`,` and `"` by default, respectively). Finally, in the future make sure to follow the EE update instructions, especially steps 3 and 4: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html

Comment: I have followed those specifications about the CSV file exactly, and after several rounds of testing, the Internal Server Error has continued to occur only on files importing over 40 rows (+ first row as titles). This is regardless of file size, as one file importing 41 rows was smaller and produced an error, than another larger file importing 40 rows successfully.

Comment: Here is a link to my server's error log, looks like it's timing out at 45 seconds each time: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzuj1ioqvpmzadq/error_log

Comment: When troubleshooting, try using the **same** file/dataset between tests (eg. a file with 100 rows, and another with 40 rows, but both have the same first 40 rows). Using different files with different data in each makes it harder to pinpoint an issue.

Comment: That said, can you open a ticket over at support.solspace.com? Please give us CP and FTP credentials, the name of the Import profile that you are using, as well as the CSV file that is causing you issues. Thanks!